# How can i convert an Array to ES6 new Map type?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Imagine i have an array such as:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

ObjX is something like:

```
{id:'something',a:1,b:2,...}
```

How do i convert it to ES6 Map type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
let firstArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
// i randomly selected id to be my Map key, could be any other
let myKeyValueArray = firstArray.map(item=>[item.id,item])
let myMap = new Map(myKeyValueArray)
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Why did you post and answer on your question at the same time...

Comment: Because i just wasted time searching for this answer. Might help others.

Comment: @Alex Self answers are fine [and actually encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: However, the question needs work in order for the answer to make sense.  How would one guess from the question that the map is supposed to be keyed on `id`?

Comment: I second that this question needs to be more clear.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, op could look to the dupe target ... ;-)

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes, but a reader can only get the full scope of the question by looking at the answer.  Something wrong there.  :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Map doesn't need to be keyed on id. This is question is nowhere in Stackoverflow. Added comment to clarify.

Comment: @ScottSauyet > a reader can only get the full scope of the question by looking at the answer > Question is straight forward. There is nothing else to add.

Comment: @NinaScholz a reference to ES6 in the question you marked would have enabled me to find it.

Comment: Well, if you don't care what the key is, you could always do `new Map(Object.entries(myArray))`.  :-)  My point was that one couldn't answer your question in any helpful way without more information.  "How do i convert it to ES6 Map type?" has many legitimate, but incompatible, answers.